# Best unicode font to work with minted in xelatex/lualatex

Tags: xetex, minted

I have a bunch of unicode heavy (Julia) code that I want to plot with `minted` and am having trouble getting the unicode to display.  For example, take the following code

```
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
```

Now, put this in a xelatex file

```
% !TEX engine = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmonofont{Consolas} %Might be better ones?
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{julia}
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum # Although `sum` may be just as good in the code.
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you will see that the $\pi$ and $\Sigma$ work fine, but the `\odot` and $\in$ do not.  Is this something that I need to pick a better `monofont` for?  Do I need other packages?  Etc.

Comment: See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2297/fontsupport.htm You can search for unicode characters and then for fonts that support them.  The DejaVu family may be a good choice for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can fill in the gaps by making the characters active with a suitable definition

[image]

```
% !TEX engine = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{∈}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\in$}}
\newunicodechar{⊗}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\otimes$}}
\setmonofont{Consolas} %Might be better ones?
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{julia}
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum # Although `sum` may be just as good in the code.
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! `\newunicodechar`!

Comment: @egreg the package doesn't have the simple elegance of `indentfirst` but it has its uses sometimes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You and egreg are the best. +1.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid having to define characters, you could switch to a font that has those characters. The GNU FreeMono font is a good one since it is free and has over 4,000 characters. It has a much larger character set than most monospace fonts, including the previously missing math characters you needed. You can download it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/

This is an updated example using the FreeMono font that displays the missing characters.

```
% !TEX engine = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmonofont{FreeMono} %switched to FreeMono
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{julia}
f(x) = x.^2 + π
const ⊗ = kron
const Σ = sum # Although `sum` may be just as good in the code.
# Calculate Σ_{j=1}^5 j^2
Σ([j^2 for j ∈ 1:5])
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: FreeMono output]

Comment: nks. Are there any of these fonts that are part of a typical miktex installation, or download able from CTAN ? I would prefer not to have additional setup instructions

Comment: I'm not sure if it comes with miktex, but since you are already using xelatex, you just have to download the fonts in otf version (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/freefont-otf-20080323.zip) to your system and install them normally, which is a painless process usually. Xelatex with then be able to access your system fonts, without any special latex-related extra steps.