# Which font should I use to get Julia's code with bold letter using minted in xelatex/lualatex?

Tags: minted, code, julia

I've searched on how to create Julia's code on LaTex and I [found](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-do-you-use-to-embed-julia-code-in-latex/23992) [very](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500683/complete-setup-for-xelatex-or-lualatex-in-vscode-with-julia-code-using-minted/) [good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212793/how-can-i-typeset-julia-code-with-the-listings-package) [references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422039/best-unicode-font-to-work-with-minted-in-xelatex-lualatex). However, the code does not compile properly when it has bold letters, e.g.,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmonofont{FreeMono} %switched to FreeMono

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true, linenos, numbersep=3pt, gobble=2, frame=lines, fontsize=\small, framesep=2mm]{julia}
    using Convex, SCS, Plots, LaTeXStrings

    N = 30 # N in the set {0, 1, ..., N}
    n = 3 # order of the linear dynamical system
    x_des = [7, 2, -6] # constraint -> (N) == x_des
    # model parameters
     = [-1 .4 .8; 1 0 0; 0 1 0]
     = [1, 0, 0.3]

     = Variable(n, N+1) # [(0) (1) ... (N)]
     = Variable(1, N) # [u(0) u(1) ... u(N-1)]
    f0 = sum(max(abs(), 2abs()-1)) # objective function
    constraints = [
        [:,2:N+1] == *[:,1:N]+*, # recursive equation
        [:,1] == zeros(n), # initial condition
        [:,N+1] == x_des, # final condition
    ]
    problem = minimize(f0, constraints)
    solve!(problem, SCS.Optimizer; silent_solver = true)

    fig = plot(vec(.value), xlabel=L"k", title=L"u(k)", line=:steppre)
    savefig(fig, "figs/4.17.png")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am pretty sure that it is caused by the font. I tried to use [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) (MesloLGMDZ Nerd Font) in order to get the right font, but `fontspec` does not allow patched fonts...

Which font should I use to get a beautiful Julia's code with bold letter?

PS: I could solve it by using `Noto Sans Math`, but the font is quite ugly, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You need a font with the Unicode math alphabets. I use Stix Two Math here. Simplest is to use it directly, as here, and give up monospace. You could in principle make a Lua virtual font that enforced monospace and/or used a different monospace font for the ascii range.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newfontfamily\stm{StixTwoMath}[NFSSFamily=stm]
\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmonofont{FreeMono} %switched to FreeMono

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true, linenos, numbersep=3pt, gobble=2, frame=lines, fontsize=\small, fontfamily=stm, framesep=2mm]{julia}
    using Convex, SCS, Plots, LaTeXStrings

    N = 30 # N in the set {0, 1, ..., N}
    n = 3 # order of the linear dynamical system
    x_des = [7, 2, -6] # constraint -> (N) == x_des
    # model parameters
     = [-1 .4 .8; 1 0 0; 0 1 0]
     = [1, 0, 0.3]

     = Variable(n, N+1) # [(0) (1) ... (N)]
     = Variable(1, N) # [u(0) u(1) ... u(N-1)]
    f0 = sum(max(abs(), 2abs()-1)) # objective function
    constraints = [
        [:,2:N+1] == *[:,1:N]+*, # recursive equation
        [:,1] == zeros(n), # initial condition
        [:,N+1] == x_des, # final condition
    ]
    problem = minimize(f0, constraints)
    solve!(problem, SCS.Optimizer; silent_solver = true)

    fig = plot(vec(.value), xlabel=L"k", title=L"u(k)", line=:steppre)
    savefig(fig, "figs/4.17.png")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

You can look for other fonts with   (U+1D417) using `albatross` which is in texlive

```
$ albatross U+1D417 
        __ __           __
.---.-.|  |  |--.---.-.|  |_.----.-----.-----.-----.
|  _  ||  |  _  |  _  ||   _|   _|  _  |__ --|__ --|
|___._||__|_____|___._||____|__| |_____|_____|_____|

                    Unicode code point [1D417] mapping to ?
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
│ Font name                                                                   │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Asana Math                                                                  │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Asana Math,Asana                                                            │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Cambria                                                                     │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Cambria Math                                                                │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Concrete Math                                                               │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ DejaVu Math TeX Gyre                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ DejaVu Serif                                                                │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed                                         │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Erewhon Math                                                                │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Euler Math                                                                  │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Fira Math                                                                   │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ FreeSerif                                                                   │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Garamond\-Math                                                              │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ GFS Neohellenic Math                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ KpMath                                                                      │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Latin Modern Math                                                           │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Libertinus Math                                                             │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ NewComputerModernMath                                                       │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Segoe UI Symbol                                                             │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ STIX                                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ STIX Math                                                                   │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ STIX Two Math                                                               │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Symbola                                                                     │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ TeX Gyre Bonum Math                                                         │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ TeX Gyre DejaVu Math                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ TeX Gyre Pagella Math                                                       │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ TeX Gyre Schola Math                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ TeX Gyre Termes Math                                                        │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Unifont Upper                                                               │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ XCharter Math                                                               │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ XITS Math                                                                   │ 
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: 1. where to download `Stix Two Math`? 2. Where can I search for fontspec-compliant fonts?

Comment: Stix is part of texlive so you may have it already   is U+1D417 and various tools will tell you which fonts have that character. texlive includes `albatross` on my machine`albatros U+1D417` lists  (too long, I'll add to answer)  @RubemPacelli

Comment: `albatross`  is a CTAN package that is in `texlive-font-utils` on Ubuntu:
`❯ sudo apt show texlive-font-utils | rg -i 'albatross'
 albatross -- Find fonts that contain a given glyph`, which is already installed. But it is not on `$PATH`. How can invoke it from my terminal?

Comment: that's odd, looks like an error in the apt packaging for albatross, I'll ping Paulo (who wrote it) to comment. it should be in the same place as `tex` so be in the PATH if tex is @RubemPacelli

Answer (score 2):

Just a additional info: You can also use [this site](https://mono-math.netlify.app/) to help you to see fonts with math glyphs. For instance, I will put here the code by using JuliaMono font

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\newfontfamily \JuliaMono {JuliaMono-Regular.ttf}[
    Path      = /home/tapyu/.local/share/fonts/juliamono/,
    Extension = .ttf
    ]

\newfontface \JuliaMonoRegular{JuliaMono-Regular}

\setmonofont{JuliaMonoRegular}[
    Contextuals=Alternate
]

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true, linenos, numbersep=3pt, gobble=2, frame=lines, fontsize=\small, framesep=2mm]{julia}
    using Convex, SCS, Plots, LaTeXStrings

    N = 30 # N in the set {0, 1, ..., N}
    n = 3 # order of the linear dynamical system
    x_des = [7, 2, -6] # constraint -> (N) == x_des
    # model parameters
     = [-1 .4 .8; 1 0 0; 0 1 0]
     = [1, 0, 0.3]

     = Variable(n, N+1) # [(0) (1) ... (N)]
     = Variable(1, N) # [u(0) u(1) ... u(N-1)]
    f0 = sum(max(abs(), 2abs()-1)) # objective function
    constraints = [
        [:,2:N+1] == *[:,1:N]+*, # recursive equation
        [:,1] == zeros(n), # initial condition
        [:,N+1] == x_des, # final condition
    ]
    problem = minimize(f0, constraints)
    solve!(problem, SCS.Optimizer; silent_solver = true)

    fig = plot(vec(.value), xlabel=L"k", title=L"u(k)", line=:steppre)
    savefig(fig, "figs/4.17.png")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

It yields
[image]

Acknowledge: Thanks are due to the [Julia community discourse channel](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-do-you-use-to-embed-julia-code-in-latex/)